# Unable to use puppeteer in a nodejs app on cpanel?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, cpanel

I am using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) in my nodejs application to convert html file into pdf. This is working fine in my local server and pdf is getting generated. But this is not working in cPanel. I am getting error similar to [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6755). I tried everything mentioned on that but nothing works.

I tried setting the executable path of chrome in puppeteer in cpanel but in vain. Errpr =>

```
Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/xxx/public_html/xxx/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-1002410/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried different packages like html-pdf and node-pdf-generator. But the problem is I have designed some ejs templates according to chrome and then I am generating html files from these ejs templates. After that I am saving the pdf file in buffer and uploading this buffer to google bucket.

> Flow: [ejs templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) -> html file -> pdf buffer -> [stream buffer to gc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_createWriteStream_member_1_)
> bucket

In other packages I am facing these issues:

1. Either the template is not coming as expected
2. Or The package has no option of storing generated pdf file in buffer.

Any solution or a different library?

Comment: Puppeteer uses chromium. as you see from the error it was unable to find the chromium path, try by mentioning the path where you have chromium downloaded. Puppeteer can automatically download and install chromium also. please go through the puppeteer documentation. In cPanel you application might not have access to  folders.

Comment: @RichardVinoth yes I do have mentioned the path. The error I highlighted above is coming after giving the path. According to that error cpanel is missing a library libatk-1-0-so-0 but I don't have admin rights and I can't install that. Is there any other solution or a different library ?